# ¿Como puedo mostrar la informacion detalla de los personajes en mi aplicacion?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, observable

¿cómo están?, recientemente he estado creando un proyecto en angular sobre consumiendo datos API REST con los personajes de Rick And Morty, siguiendo el siguiente tutorial:
[Link de video del tutorial con el minuto exacto](https://youtu.be/hGU2ceM8aVY?t=4834). El problema que tengo con es cuando, quiero ver detalladamente las características del personaje, no me sale nada.
[Imagen de la aplicacion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drnst.jpg). He estado revisando en mi código:

Character-details.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CharacterService } from '@shared/services/character.service';
import { Character } from '@shared/interfaces/character.interface';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-character-details',
  templateUrl: './character-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./character-details.component.scss'],
})
  
export class CharacterDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  character$!: Observable<Character>;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private characterSvc: CharacterService,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((params) => {
      const id = params['id'];
      //this.character$?.subscribe(x => this.characterSvc.getDetails(id)); 
      this.character$ = this.characterSvc.getDetails(id);
      
    });
  }

  onGoBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

Character.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Character } from '../interfaces/character.interface';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CharacterService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getDetails(id: number) {
    return this.http
      .get<Character>(`${environment.baseUrlAPI}/${id}`)
      .pipe(catchError((err) => this.handleHttpError(err)));
  }

  searchCharacters(
    query = '',
    page = 200
  ): Observable<Character[]> {
    const filter = `${environment.baseUrlAPI}/?name=${query}&page=${page}`;
    return this.http
      .get<Character[]>(filter)
  }

  handleHttpError(err: any): any {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }

  
}
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrlAPI: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/"
};
```

Character interface.ts

```
export interface Character {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  image: string;
  species: string;
  gender: string;
  created: string;
  status: string;
}
```

y me sale el siguiente error:

[Error sobre el método que no deja revisar los personajes detallademente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaaF3.png)

```
(property) CharacterDetailsComponent.character$: Observable<Character>
Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Character>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Character'.ts(2322)
```

He estado revisando el codigo del video, pero nada que encuentro como solucionarlo, he estado siguiente el video detalladamente, pero como es un poco viejo toca hacerle modificaciones, si alguien me ayudaría estaría agradecido:

Aquí dejo el link del repositorio mio por si necesitan más información: [Repositorio mio](https://github.com/JuanfelipeX/RickAndMortyApp)

El link del repositorio de la persona del video: [Repositorio de la persona del video](https://github.com/domini-code/ricky_morty_app)

Comment: puedes poner los fragmentos de código directamente, no es necesario pasar un repositorio o imágenes, así dudo que te ayuden

Comment: listo ya agrege mas fragmentos de codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas obteniendo este error, porque tienes marcado el tipo de retorno del método `handleHttpError` del servicio como del tipo `any`.

```
export class CharacterService {
  ...

  handleHttpError(err: any): any { // <------------- aquí
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  
}
```

Esto provoca, que al poder devolver este método cualquier cosa, Typescript no sepa como inferir el tipo resultante que devolvería el operador `catchError` de `getDetails` en caso de que se produjera un error en la petición http. Y de ahí que directamente lo marque como desconocido o `unknown`.

Para solucionarlo, como de momento simplemente tiras un error, puedes marcar *temporalmente* el tipo de retorno de `handleHttpError` como del tipo `never`. Esto le indicará a Typescript que por la via de este método el flujo se interrumpe y entonces podrá inferir correctamente el tipo de retorno de `getDetails`

```
handleHttpError(err: any): never { 
  throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
}
```

Recuerda que cuando implementes el código final de `handleHttpError` deberás también ajustar este tipo de retorno.

un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score -1):

Ese error pasa por que estas tipando el retorno del observable a 'Character' y cuando haces tu consulta `http.get` angular no sabe lo que esta retornando, por eso lo parsea como 'unknown'. Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un `.pipe` y un `map` dentro del `pipe` para parsear el tipo de dato de `unknown` a `Character`

```js
getDetails(id: number) {
  return this.http
    .get < Character > (`${environment.baseUrlAPI}/${id}`)
    .pipe(
      map(response => {

        //Comprueba que verdaderamente estas recibiendo
        // un json con la estructura de tipo Character
        
        console.log(response)
        let objetoParseado = response as Character
        return objetoParseado

      }),
      catchError((err) => this.handleHttpError(err))

    );
}
```